# One button for file select and upload

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to create only one button which selects the file and uploads too..
I created one button which selects the file but it doesn't fire the onclick function in the upload button.

For an example I have one hello button which just consoles something but in reality it will do something with the selected file.

```
    <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
       <button class="btn" onClick ="hello()">Upload a file</button>
       <input type="file" name="myfile"/>
    </div>



.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}


function hello() {
 console.log("hello");
}
```

Link for codePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wOmNJw

Answer (score 0):

The input is overriding the button click listener. If you are trying to do something with the file then you should apply a change listener to the input and run a function there. You can do this with or without jquery.

**Vanilla JS (No Jquery)**

```js
document.getElementsByName('myfile')[0].addEventListener('change', function(){
    hello(this);
});


function hello(elem) {
    console.log('Hello');
    console.log('File Name: ', elem.value);
}
```

```css
.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
       <button class="btn" onClick ="hello()">Upload a file</button>
       <input type="file" name="myfile"/>
    </div>
```

**With JQuery**

```js
$('input[name="myfile"]').on('change', hello);

function hello() {
 console.log("hello");
}
```

```css
.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
       <button class="btn" onClick ="hello()">Upload a file</button>
       <input type="file" name="myfile"/>
    </div>
```

**Edit: React Example**

```js
// Example class component
class InputExample extends React.Component {
  handleFileChange(e){
      console.log('Hello');
      console.log('File Name: ', e.target.value);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        id="upload" 
        ref="upload" 
        type="file" 
        accept="image/*"       
        multiple="false"
        onChange={(e) => this.handleFileChange(e)}/>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <InputExample />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your original question didn't mention react but sure see my edit for a react example.

Answer (score 0):

I maked a few changes in your code and it works:

JS file

```
function hello() {
  console.log("hello");

    document.querySelector('.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file]').click();
}
```

CSS file

```
.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If this is what you are looking for.

```js
document.getElementById("fileInput").addEventListener("change", function(event, val){
  let file = event.target.value;
  
  if(!!file){
     document.getElementById("inputWrapper").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("upload").style.display = "block";
  }

});
```

```css
.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">

  <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn" style="display:none" id="upload" />

  <div id="inputWrapper">
    <span><input type="file" name="myfile" id="fileInput"/></span>
    <span><button class="btn">Select file</button>    </span>
  </div>

</div>
```